# Enabling MetalRenderer in simulator leads to Crash

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, metal, google-maps-sdk-ios

Has anyone been able to get GoogleMaps running in simulator with GMSServices.setMetalRendererEnabled(true)

I'm looking to evaluate Google's Map performance and abilities. Given the updates to Metal I wanted to evaluate how the performance worked with and without metal enabled.

Given [GoogleMaps-Swift Sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/code-samples#:%7E:text=Download%20the%20code%20sample%20archive), I was able to get Basic map rendering up and running by setting up workspace with pod install, and by adding my APIKet. Unfortunately, when I attempted to enable Metal rendering, I get a crash. I stepped through with latest SDK + pod install workspace setup.

`GMSServices.setMetalRendererEnabled(true)`

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000008
VM Region Info: 0x8 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4560125944
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                      10fce0000-1102fc000    [ 6256K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...apsSwiftDemos
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [18316]

...
Thread 13 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.google.Maps.GMSRenderTileProvider.vector
0   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10ff41949 gmscore::renderer::MetalEntity::SetRenderState(std::__1::shared_ptr<gmscore::renderer::MetalRenderState> const&, GMSPassID) + 27
1   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10ff90a69 gmscore::vector::AreaGroup::CreateMetalFillEntities(std::__1::vector<gmscore::vector::AreaGroup::AreaSubset, std::__1::allocator<gmscore::vector::AreaGroup::AreaSubset> > const&, int, int) + 2159
2   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10ff95d24 void gmscore::vector::AreaGroup::InitializeMetal<gmscore::base::STLRange<std::__1::multiset<GMSArea* __strong, std::__1::function<bool (GMSArea*, GMSArea*)>, std::__1::allocator<GMSArea* __strong> > const> >(int, gmscore::base::STLRange<std::__1::multiset<GMSArea* __strong, std::__1::function<bool (GMSArea*, GMSArea*)>, std::__1::allocator<GMSArea* __strong> > const> const&, id<GMSStyleTable>, GMSModelStyle*) + 2536
3   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10ff8f64c void gmscore::vector::AreaGroup::Initialize<gmscore::base::STLRange<std::__1::multiset<GMSArea* __strong, std::__1::function<bool (GMSArea*, GMSArea*)>, std::__1::allocator<GMSArea* __strong> > const> const&>(int, gmscore::base::STLRange<std::__1::multiset<GMSArea* __strong, std::__1::function<bool (GMSArea*, GMSArea*)>, std::__1::allocator<GMSArea* __strong> > const> const&, id<GMSStyleTable>, GMSModelStyle*) + 202
4   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10ff8f51f gmscore::vector::AreaGroup::AreaGroup(GMSTileCoords*, int, gmscore::base::STLRange<std::__1::multiset<GMSArea* __strong, std::__1::function<bool (GMSArea*, GMSArea*)>, std::__1::allocator<GMSArea* __strong> > const> const&, gmscore::vector::ZOrdering const&, id<GMSStyleTable>, id<GMSEntityResources>, GMSServerResourceManager*, GMSPassID, GMSModelStyle*) + 287
5   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10fff1b4e void gmscore::vector::AreaGroup::CreateGroups<std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<id<GMSFeature> __strong, std::__1::__tree_node<id<GMSFeature>, void*>*, long>, std::__1::back_insert_iterator<std::__1::vector<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::FeatureGroup>, std::__1::allocator<gmscore::vector::FeatureGroup> > > >(std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<id<GMSFeature> __strong, std::__1::__tree_node<id<GMSFeature>, void*>*, long>, std::__1::back_insert_iterator<std::__1::vector<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::FeatureGroup>, std::__1::allocator<gmscore::vector::FeatureGroup> > >, GMSTileCoords*, int, id<GMSStyleTable>, id<GMSEntityResources>, GMSServerResourceManager*, GMSPassID, int, GMSModelStyle*, std::__1::back_insert_iterator<std::__1::vector<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::FeatureGroup>, std::__1::allocator<gmscore::vector::FeatureGroup> > >) + 376
6   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10fff188d -[GMSUWFRenderTile buildLayeredEntitiesFromLayers:entityResources:resourceManager:] + 131
7   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10fff127c -[GMSUWFRenderTile buildEntitiesWithEntityResources:resourceManager:] + 222
8   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10ffd7f6d -[GMSRenderTileProvider buildEntitiesForTile:tileInfo:] + 132
9   GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10ffd7e26 -[GMSRenderTileProvider prepareEntitiesForTile:tileInfo:] + 214
10  GoogleMapsSwiftDemos                   0x10ffd7c18 __66-[GMSRenderTileProvider prepareRenderTile:tileInfo:tilePrepTimer:]_block_invoke + 109
```

Some considerations:

- Is this only for device to enabled? If so, does it need to be documented in the headers?
- Is there something I'm missing to be able to enable properly?

Links:
[Crash Report](https://gist.github.com/dmiluski/cdb1e98ed33a934aa430948c090cd83e)

Comment: Does it run as expected on a device?

Comment: Hi @JeshuaLacock,

As a matter of fact it does run on device. I'm able to build and run to device in debug mode and it doesn't crash.

What's leaving me confused is I'm contributing to a team project and if I'm unable to get it to function in simulator, it would block other developers.

Comment: Current Dev hardward:
- MacOS Monterey: 12.2.1 (21D62)
- 2019 Macbook Pro
- 2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
- Memory: 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4GB Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Comment: Is this still happening? Did you try reporting this issue in Google's Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188833&template=789005